# Eclipse not refreshing

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting an error on line 33 in my class, even after I comment that line out, save and close eclipse, refresh the file, move more code around, and repeat. Still when I try to run my app (using Run As... Android Application), I get the same error on line 33, even though the code on which it's calling an error no longer exists. The error is in class declarations, so I tried adding int error_here = 1/0; before line 33, but I still get the same error.

The error I'm getting is:

```
04-10 21:26:20.884: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()J
04-10 21:26:20.884: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
04-10 21:26:20.884: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:441)
04-10 21:26:20.884: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.rose.camerapreview.CameraPreviewActivity.<init>(CameraPreviewActivity.java:33)
```

Of course, that call to create a new `Mat` no longer exists.

Here's the code:

```
CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView; // this is line 35 now
native int annotateORB (long l);
int error_here = 1/0;

//Mat mImage = new Mat();
public final String TIME_TAG = "time_tag";
private static boolean mShouldAnnotateORB = true;
```

Comment: How are you running your program?  What is your class path when you're running it?  What is your Eclipse build output path?

Comment: You're going to have to seriously add more detail. Code, config, error message, etc.

Comment: can you check if your classfile is getting modified after AND you have build automatically checked true

Comment: Yes, `Project > Build Automatically` is checked, and I removed my Activity's `class files from bin/classes/package_name`. When I ran the app again, these class files were recreated.

Comment: Did you try Project > Clean..?

Comment: Yes. I also made sure that `Project > Properties > Android > Is Library is unchecked.

Comment: Try to create a new java file with slightly different name from your original one; containing the same code (without the `Mat`).. and see whether it works well.. if it does, perhaps there is a cache of your java file somewhere that we don't know (created by eclipse)..

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a build-automatically problem.

Check Eclipse menu **Project** -> **Build Automatically** is **CHECKED** , like this `√`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a clean?

In the *Top Menú*: **Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects**.

If the problem has not been resolved, restart **Eclipse**.